# Dropdown menu Umbraco

Tags: html, .net, razor, drop-down-menu, umbraco7

I made a menu for umbraco but I can't get the dropdown to work! Below is my code:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

                    <div class="NavDigiCampuz">
                        <div>
                            <div class="nav nav-list tree">
                                @{                                  
                                    var documentRootNodeId = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("documentRoot", true); // Fetch recursive document root id.
                                    var selection = Umbraco.TypedContent(documentRootNodeId).Children.Where("Visible"); // Select all nodes below the document root.
                                }

                                @foreach(var item in Model.Content.Ancestor(1).Descendants("menu")){
                                    foreach (var Menus in @item.Descendants("menuItem")){
                                        <li class="MenuItems">@Menus.Name</li>  
                                            foreach (var MenuItems in @Menus.Children){
                                                if(MenuItems.GetPropertyValue("hoofdstukIcoon") != "") {
                                                <li><a class="NormalA" href="@MenuItems.Url"><i class="fa fa-@(MenuItems.GetPropertyValue("hoofdstukIcoon")) fa-fw"></i> @MenuItems.Name</a></li>
                                                    }else {
                                                            <li><a class="NormalA"href="@MenuItems.Url">@MenuItems.Name</a></li>



                                                var childIsActive = false;

                                                    foreach(var sub in @MenuItems.Children){
                                                    if (CurrentPage.Url == sub.Url) {
                                                        childIsActive = true;
                                                    }



                                            <ul class="nav subnav nav-list tree @(childIsActive ? "" : "collapse")">
                                                @foreach(var sub2 in @MenuItems.Children){
                                                    <li @(CurrentPage.Url == sub.Url ? "class=active" : "")>
                                                        <a onclick="parent.resizeParent();" href="@sub.Url">@(sub.GetPropertyValue("hoofdstukMenuTitel") != "" ? sub.GetPropertyValue("hoofdstukMenuTitel") : sub.GetPropertyValue("hoofdstukTitel"))</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                }
                                            </ul>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                }
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The dropdown code should start at `<ul class="nav subnav nav-list tree @(childIsActive ? "" : "collapse")">` but that doesn't seem to work.

Below is a quick structure of how I want my page to be: [image: Menu Structure]

Help item 3 should have a dropdown which it doesn't have right now. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have some inconsistencies in your structure:
this line:

```
<div class="nav nav-list tree">
```

should be this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list tree">
```

And I would remove the `<div>` that wrapps it.

I'm just guessing you are using something like bootstrap, are you using a framework or custom css?

Your submenu should also be nested in the `<li>` element:

```
else
 {
     <li><a class="NormalA" href="@MenuItems.Url">@MenuItems.Name</a>
         var childIsActive = false;
         foreach (var sub in @MenuItems.Children)
         {
            if (CurrentPage.Url == sub.Url)
            {
             childIsActive = true;
            }

           <ul class="nav subnav nav-list tree @(childIsActive ? "" : "collapse")">
               @foreach (var sub2 in @MenuItems.Children)
               {
                 <li @(CurrentPage.Url == sub.Url ? "class=active" : "")>
                    <a onclick="parent.resizeParent();" href="@sub.Url">@(sub.GetPropertyValue("hoofdstukMenuTitel") != "" ? sub.GetPropertyValue("hoofdstukMenuTitel") : sub.GetPropertyValue("hoofdstukTitel"))</a>
                 </li>
               }
           </ul>
          }
      </li>

}
```